# How do you wait for a return from a function before moving on in node

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm new to Node so I'm struggling with this. The script runs as if its "skipping" the `bitx.getTicker` function inside the while loop. I did some research on asynchronous functions in Node and I just cant seem to get it working on my code. I'm trying to write a crypto-bot with bitx. I tried the .then() method as well and it just keeps on "skipping" the bitx.getTicker function. If I remove the `async`(from line 1), ``` let tick = await``(from line 5) and the ``` while``` loop it works as intended but just once. I need it to run constantly to check new asking price so once wont work. Thanks in advance.

```
async function get_ticker(){
  let BitX = require('../lib/BitX')
  while(true){
    let bitx = new BitX(key, secret)
    let tick = await bitx.getTicker(function (err, ticker) {
      // sends ticker object to another function to get values
      get_info(ticker)
    })

    console.log(i)
    i = i + 1
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I used a promise and I see it pending but I cant access the `ticker` variable inside the `bitx.getTicker function`. How can I access it?

```
function get_ticker() {
  let BitX = require('../lib/BitX')

  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let bitx = new BitX(key, secret)
    bitx.getTicker(function (err, ticker) {
      resolve(ticker)
    })

  })
  return promise.resolve
}

var result = get_ticker()
console.log(result)
```

Comment: It keeps skipping because you have passed a callback to `getTicker` method. You can either use callback-based API or use promises if `BitX` provides a method that returns a promise. With your current code, there's no point in awaiting `bite.getTicker`. If `bite.getTicker` doesn't return a promise, you can promising it using node's built-in `util` module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Yousaf. I updated my question and it looks like it works fine now but how would you access the ticker variable? I tried it in the above and I see the promise **pending** but I cant access the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your BitX library doesn't have a promise interface but is callback-based, so you need to promisify it:

```js
const { promisify } = require('util')

async function get_ticker(){
  let BitX = require('../lib/BitX')
  while(true){
    let bitx = new BitX(key, secret)
    let tick = await promisify(bitx.getTicker).call(bitx)
    get_info(tick)

    console.log(i)
    i = i + 1
  }
}
```

It would be more performant to create the client only once though:

```js
const { promisify } = require('util')
const BitX = require('../lib/BitX')
const bitx = new BitX(key, secret)
const getBitxTicker = promisify(bitx.getTicker).bind(bitx)

async function get_ticker(){
  while(true){
    const tick = await getBitxTicker()
    get_info(tick)

    console.log(i)
    i = i + 1
  }
}
```

(Note that I used `bind` instead of `call` now for binding the `bitx` instance, because we don't immediately call it now.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @CherryDT. It works perfect if I pass ```tick`` to the ```get_info``` function. I just want to ask, if I only created the client once, wont I receive the same values the whole time? I want to receive live values, that's why I thought to create it repeatedly.  Please let me know. Thanks :)

Comment: You still ask the (same) client every time to check the values by calling its getTicker function so you won't receive the same.